# Change Date into Month Name and Date with Year in C#

Tags: c#, date, date-format

I want to convert the date into something different. I give input date, it will convert into that format.

**My code**

```
 var dt = erd.StartDate.Value.ToShortDateString();

 var format = String.Format("{MMM/D/yyyy}", dt);
```

Here it is showing an error like `input string is not correct format.`

Help me to find out the issue?

Comment: what format do you want to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply rewrite it like this (I'm assuming the erd.StartDate.Value datatype is datetime)

```
string result = erd.StartDate.Value.ToString("MMM/dd/yyyy");
```

or using "D" is equivalent to "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy"

```
string result = erd.StartDate.Value.ToString("D");
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need to use small `d` for representing Date.
2. you should not convert the Date into String before applying the custom Format.

Try This:

```
var dt = erd.StartDate.Value;
var format =dt.ToString("MMM/d/yyyy");
```

Comment: A big 'D' can also be used to represent a Long Date as specified here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720651(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @rhughes, "D" is equivalent to "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy" and it should be used alone. see my sample and give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

To solve your error, try the below code:

```
var dt = erd.StartDate.Value;

var format = String.Format("{0:MMMM/dd/yyyy}", dt);
```

You need to specify the parameter index to use. In the above code, we are telling `String.Format` to use parameter `0` to be formatted as a `DateTime`.

`DateTime` formatting has many types. Please see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa720651%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for the different things you can do.

Comment: What makes you think that once date is converted to string, the `format` method will re-interpret it as `DateTime` and do the format again?

Comment: For that it should be a `DateTime` object already, it won't do type conversion based on the format as far I know, feel free to correct me.

Comment: No issues, this is the same problem with OP :)

Comment: my output is showing DaysFeb/D/2014.. But i don't want to display Days. what will do?

Comment: sorry. After try the updated code i got normal one only.

Comment: @Duk Updated again :)